# remove the delete icon from the previous uploaded image and add delete icon for new uploaded images in antd upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, antd, image-upload

[issue-i'm-getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrGEH.png)
I'm implementing photo gallery where i will get the images from the api, and those images will have only the preview option.
when new photo i add from the UI i want to show to preview and delete option only for newly added photos before i click on save button.

```
const previewConfig = {
    showPreviewIcon: true,
    showDownloadIcon: false,
    showRemoveIcon: props?.key=== 'Gallery_photos' ? true : false,
    removeIcon: (file: any) => {
      if (file?.disableDelete) {
        return <></>;
      } else {
        return <DeleteOutlined onClick={() => NewAddedImageRemove(file)} title='Remove Image' />
      }

    },
  };
```

the above code does show the the result i expected but,

the if condition only remove the delete icon and in antd internal it has button which shows the title "Remove file" on hover of delete icon place.

How to remove the button delete button completely and show only when condition is not satisfied.

I have tried removing it from the DOM.

```
const previewConfig = {
    showPreviewIcon: true,
    showDownloadIcon: false,
    showRemoveIcon: props?.key === 'Gallery_photos' ? true : false,
    removeIcon: (file: any) => {
      if (file?.disableDelete) {
        let temp: any = document.getElementsByClassName('ant-btn css-1wazalj ant-btn-text ant-btn-sm ant-btn-icon-only ant-upload-list-item-action')[0];
        temp?.parentNode.removeChild(temp)
        return;
      } else {
        return <DeleteOutlined onClick={() => NewAddedImageRemove(file)} title='Remove Image' />
      }
    },
  };
```

by doing this 1st time when i add the photo the delete icon is visible and 2nd when i add one more photo delete icon gets added to 2nd time added image and removing it from the 1st time upload.

I want delete icon to be present to all the newly added images.